# How to get only newest records on every same record when using hasMany() in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

So, I have something like this :

```
class Student {
    /**
     * Get the counseling_requests for the student.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function counselingRequests()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CounselingRequest::class);
    }
}
```

**CounselingRequest** structure :

- id
- student_id
- lecturer_schedule_id
- status
- deleted_at
- created_at
- updated_at

I need to have resulted from **counselingRequests()**, when it has same lecturer_schedule_id, it must be only returned the newest CounselingRequest.

Example (now) the result from counselingRequests() :

```
id | student_id | lecturer_schedule_id | status | created_at
1  | 1          | 2                    | 0      | 2016-09-01
2  | 1          | 2                    | 1      | 2016-09-02
3  | 1          | 3                    | 1      | 2016-09-02
4  | 1          | 4                    | 0      | 2016-09-03
```

Expected result :

```
id | student_id | lecturer_schedule_id | status | created_at
2  | 1          | 2                    | 1      | 2016-09-02
3  | 1          | 3                    | 1      | 2016-09-02
4  | 1          | 4                    | 0      | 2016-09-03
```

Comment: Check out this link: https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-latest-related-model/

Comment: @OvidiuBadita Yes, I have read the article several times. But, I think the example (case) is different with my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For identical `lecturer_schedule_id`, `group_by` would pick the last one and then sort in ascending order.

```
Student::with(['councelingRequests'=>function($query)
          {
            $query->groupBy('lecturer_schedule_id')
           }])->get();
```

You will however get:

```
id | student_id | lecturer_schedule_id | status | created_at
3  | 1          | 3                    | 1      | 2016-09-02
4  | 1          | 4                    | 0      | 2016-09-03
2  | 1          | 2                    | 1      | 2016-09-02
```

Comment: Yes, I know about it (when using 'with'). But the problem, my implementation is passing $counselingRequests variable to the views. So, instead $student->with('counselingRequests'), I use $counselingRequests = $student->counselingRequests()->with('other_relationship');

Comment: Should I change the implementation to be like that?

Comment: Aah, I think your answer should be accepted. I just realize if my problem not about it. Instead of creating the other question, I'll ask here.

Comment: So, my problem how to get the newest but when the newest has been deleted (soft deletes), it shouldn't need to be included. Tell me how..

Comment: Even if you soft delete the record, it will not be included. Soft deleted records require special treatment to be included.

Comment: Yes, it isn't included, but it includes the row that not deleted. In my case, if the newest is deleted, all the rows shouldn't be included (rows that have the same lecturer_schedule_id with it).